# Formally smooth vs. smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

A (commutative) algebra $A$ is called *formally smooth* if for any (commutative) algebra $R$ and an ideal $I\subset R$ such that $I^2=0$, any morphism $A\to R/I$ lifts to a morphism $A\to R$.

Suppose now that $X$ is a variety and $A$ is the algebra of regular functions on it.

> How are the definitions of formal smoothness of $A$ and smoothness of the variety $X$ related?

Are the two notions equivalent? It doesn't seem to be the case, but I don't know how to prove it. I might be very silly here. In this case I would be glad if you explain that to me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't introduced a base-ring for the various algebras in play; let me denote
it by $A_0$.  (In the case of varieties, we would take $A_0$ to be a field, but that
doesn't affect anything.)

For a finitely presented $A_0$-algebra $A$, formal smoothness is equivalent to smoothness.  (And if $A_0$ is Noetherian, e.g. a field, then f.p. is equivalent to finite type.)

In particular, for the affine ring of an affine variety, formal smoothness over the ground field $k$ is equivalent to the variety being smooth.

Comment: Dear Matthew, can you, please, give me a reference? Or is it supposed to be obvious and I am just being stupid?

Comment: Dear Sasha, It's a theorem of Grothendieck, originally proved somewhere in SGA IV, I think.  The reference in the stacks project is [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TN).  There is also an exercise in Hartshorne where he sketches how to deduce one direction (smoothness implies formal smoothness), probably in the section that discusses smooth morphisms.  Regards,

Comment: @SashaPatotski: Dear Sasha, Sorry, SGA IV should have read EGA IV.  Cheers,

Comment: @SashaPatotski It is probably worth mentioning that you're not stupid, that this theorem, unlike the analogue for, say, unramifiedness, is difficult.

Comment: @MattE Just for the sake of completeness: The  Hartshorne Exercise is in **Chapter II 8 Differentials** and is only converned with varieties over an algebraically closed field.